# SSL accepting self signed certificate in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, ssl, flash-builder

i am trying to use SecureSocket connection to server. i am using FlashBuilder 4.6 that has SecureSocket class implemented. the problem is that after creating SecureSocket object and calling connect function i get ioError - type 2031 and "invalid" for serverCertificateStatus. certificate on the server side is self signed. is there any way for flash to work with self signed certificates?

Comment: Generally, Flash works on top of the browser; so you'll have to add a permanent exemption in the browser for Flash to avoid this error.  If you Google around you should be able to find various instructions for your browser of choice.  I do not recommend this in a production site.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. the thing is that it is a flash client on a site, and anyone can start it with their browser, so the exemption in the browser is no got going to solve the problem.

Comment: Don't use self signed certificates in production sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`as3crypto`](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) `TLSSocket` instead (I recommend take my [patched](https://github.com/fsbmain/as3public/tree/master/as3crypto_patched) version, it has patches for several critical [issues](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/issues/list)), it also contains new method `addTrustedCertificate` that may be help in your case (just adds the certificate in *.der format, it will be accepted in any case (self signed, wrong domain and so)).

```
package
{
    import com.hurlant.crypto.tls.SSLSecurityParameters;
    import com.hurlant.crypto.tls.TLSConfig;
    import com.hurlant.crypto.tls.TLSEngine;
    import com.hurlant.crypto.tls.TLSSocket;
    import com.hurlant.util.der.PEM;
    import com.kamagames.core.util.log.Logger;
    import com.kamagames.core.util.log.TraceTarget;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.SecureSocket;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class sockettest extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="cert.pem", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private static const cert_pem:Class;

        private var tlssocket:TLSSocket;
        private var secsocket:SecureSocket;

        public function sockettest()
        {
            var cert_pem_bytes:ByteArray = new cert_pem();
            var cert_der:ByteArray = PEM.readCertIntoArray(cert_pem_bytes.readUTFBytes(cert_pem_bytes.bytesAvailable));

            var config:TLSConfig = new TLSConfig(TLSEngine.CLIENT, null, null, null, null, null, SSLSecurityParameters.PROTOCOL_VERSION);
            config.ignoreCommonNameMismatch = true;
            config.addTrustedCertificate(cert_der);

            var socket:Object = new TLSSocket(null, 0, config);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, log);
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, log);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, log);
            socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, log);
            socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, log);

            socket.connect("google.com", 443);
        }

        private function log(event:Event):void
        {
            trace(event.type);
        }
    }
}
```

In theory the `SecureSocket.addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate` method may also helps you, but I don't sure about it, may be it works only for chained certificates.

In general patched `TLSSocket` is more suitable than `SecureSocket` for applications because it opensource and gain more overall control over communication process, but `SecureSocket` is native for system as @Reboog711 mentioned (it works with system certificate for example that `TLSSocket` can't)

Comment: i have used TLSSocket and i successfully connected to the server. after connection i am sending a message and wait for a return message. now i have a problem reading return message from the server.

var o_Bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
tlssocket.readBytes( o_Bytes, 0, tlssocket.bytesAvailable );

when i trace o_Bytes there is nothing in it, and also o_Bytes.length is 0

Comment: Are you read data on _ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA_ event of socket?

Comment: on progress event i am calling a function for rading data, yes. i have added a code section that i am trying to use

Comment: may be there really isn't data, try to debug your code, for example what is the _tlssocket.bytesAvailable_ value, isn't it _0_? try remove TLS if it possible and test again your protocol and so. _TLSSocket_ works well, I tested it on several projects and didn't see the problem like yours, so it seem there is some bug in your system.

Answer (score 0):

```
tlssocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, ESecureSocketData);
private function ESecureSocketData( evt:ProgressEvent ):void
{
    StartTimer();

    ReadResponse();
    ParseMessage();
}
private function ReadResponse():void
{
    var o_Bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    tlssocket.readBytes( o_Bytes, 0, tlssocket.bytesAvailable );

    for ( var i:uint = 0; i < o_Bytes.length; i ++ ) {
        o_Bytes.position    = i;
        str_Response        += String.fromCharCode( o_Bytes.readByte() );
    }
}
```